# Codeigniter $this->cache->memcached->save('foo', 'bar', 600) returns false

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching, memcached

I'm testing memcached on Codeigniter 3.1.2 using MAMP. I have memcached showing on my phpinfo page (version: 2.2.0)

Below is my code.

```
//In the /Application/config/memcached.php file

$config = array(
    'default' => array(
        'hostname' => 'new-app.dev',
        'port' => '11211',
        'weight' => '1',
    ),
);
```

.

```
public function test_caching() {
    $this->load->driver('cache');
    var_dump($this->cache->memcached->save('foo', 'bar', 600)); // Returns false
}
```

The code below returns:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($this->cache->memcached->cache_info());

Array
(
    [new-app.dev:11211] => Array
        (
            [pid] => -1
            [uptime] => 0
            [threads] => 0
            [time] => 0
            [pointer_size] => 0
            [rusage_user_seconds] => 0
            [rusage_user_microseconds] => 0
            [rusage_system_seconds] => 0
            [rusage_system_microseconds] => 0
            [curr_items] => 0
            [total_items] => 0
            [limit_maxbytes] => 0
            [curr_connections] => 0
            [total_connections] => 0
            [connection_structures] => 0
            [bytes] => 0
            [cmd_get] => 0
            [cmd_set] => 0
            [get_hits] => 0
            [get_misses] => 0
            [evictions] => 0
            [bytes_read] => 0
            [bytes_written] => 0
            [version] => 
        )

)
```

[image]

SSL is installed on new-app.dev. Could someone please tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at `uptime` and `pid`, it looks like you did not install `memcache` server or it is not running. Memcache is not a part of `MAMP` you need to install that separately

To install Memcache server on mac simply run

`brew install memcached`

> **Memcache server** and **Memcache php Drivers** are two entirely separate things

Comment: I followed the tutorial http://www.pavlatka.cz/2016/02/mac-osx-enable-memcached-on-mamp/ to install memcached on MAMP. There was no mention of memcached server. I also check the official website of memcached https://memcached.org and got the same thing. Could you share any document on this that I can read? Thanks

Comment: @Lomse added that in answer :)